# Can't find TextView in recursive custom Listview adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I created this class called GeoArea, which is suppose to store "Geographical Area" that have children Geographical Areas, this is fairly strait foward:

```
public class GeoArea {
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public List<GeoArea> subGeoAreas;
    public GeoArea parentGeoArea;

    public GeoArea(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        name = id;
        subGeoAreas = new LinkedList<GeoArea>();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I have created the following Layout to render it on Android, the idea here is to for each GeoArea to recursively render it self and then it's children GeoArea in a listView:

```
//layout_geo_area.xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtGeoAreaName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Geo Area Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewChildGeoAreas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtGeoAreaName"
        android:gravity="left" >
    </ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my adapter I created for GeoArea to be displayed in a listView:

```
public class AdapterGeoArea extends ArrayAdapter<GeoArea>{
    private ArrayList<GeoArea> _myGeoArea;
    private Context _myContext;

    LayoutInflater _inflater;
    public AdapterGeoArea(Context context, ArrayList<GeoArea> myGeoArea) {
        super(context, 0, myGeoArea);
        _myGeoArea = myGeoArea;
        _inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        _myContext = context;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return _myGeoArea.size();
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        GeoAreaLayoutHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) { 
            convertView = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_geo_area,parent,false);
            holder = new GeoAreaLayoutHolder();
            holder.txtGeoAreaName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtGeoAreaName); 
            holder.txtGeoAreaName.setTag(convertView);
            holder.listViewChildGeoAreas = (ListView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listViewChildGeoAreas); 
            holder.listViewChildGeoAreas.setTag(convertView);

        } else { 
            holder = (GeoAreaLayoutHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
        } 

        GeoArea curGeoArea = _myGeoArea.get(position);
        holder.txtGeoAreaName.setText(curGeoArea.name);
        if(curGeoArea.subGeoAreas.size()>0){
            ArrayList<GeoArea> testList = new ArrayList<GeoArea>();
            AdapterGeoArea adapter = new AdapterGeoArea(_myContext, testList);
            for(GeoArea childGeoArea:curGeoArea.subGeoAreas){
                testList.add(childGeoArea);
            }
            holder.listViewChildGeoAreas.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    static class GeoAreaLayoutHolder { 
        public TextView txtGeoAreaName;
        public ListView listViewChildGeoAreas;
    }
}
```

And here is my Activity that I am using to set it all up:

```
public class ActivityGeoAreas extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_geo_area);

        GeoArea.searchTerm =  "Bar & Grill";

        GeoArea torontoArea = new GeoArea("cityOfToronto");

        ArrayList<GeoArea> testList = new ArrayList<GeoArea>();
        testList.add(torontoArea);

        AdapterGeoArea adapter = new AdapterGeoArea(this, testList);

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewChildGeoAreas);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

When I try to run it, I get the error nullPointerException on the line:

```
holder.txtGeoAreaName.setText(curGeoArea.name);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are still confused. ListView in `layout_geo_area.xml` and text view in another xml. textview with a custom layout inflated for each row in list view. So create `list_item.xml` in your `res/layout`. Then have textview in that xml. Inflate the same in `getView`

Comment: in your case you have a listview with each row of textview and another listview. Better use `ExpandableListView` if i understand your problem better

Comment: you inflate the same layout in your activity class and your custom adapter class. `setContentView(R.layout.layout_geo_area)` and `convertView = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_geo_area,parent,false);` its `R.layout_geo_area`. Makes no sense. I suggest you look for expandable lsitview.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check `ExpandableListView` may suit your needs better

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

An example @ http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Continuing from my previous answer to your question ( i though that solved your problem)

To display just name in your listview

list_row.xml // this is the layout with textview to be inflated in `getView`.

Each row will have textview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textGeoArea"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="Choose Area"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

layout_geo_area.xml // with only listview no textview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewChildGeoAreas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="left" >
    </ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Now your adapter class

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {  
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row,parent,false);
            // inflate list_row.xml with textview
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textGeoArea); 
            holder.setTag(convertView);

        }
        else { 
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
        } 
        GeoArea curGeoArea = _myGeoArea.get(position);
        holder.tv.setText(curGeoArea.name);

        return convertView;
    }

static class ViewHolder  // use a view holder for smooth scrolling an performance
{
TextView tv;
}
```

You have a custom adapter.

```
public class AdapterGeoArea extends ArrayAdapter<GeoArea>{
```

Now you set the adapter to listview like below

```
 AdapterGeoArea adapter = new AdapterGeoArea(this, testList);
 ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewChildGeoAreas);
 lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

So why do you need the below. remove these

```
  if(curGeoArea.subGeoAreas.size()>0){
        ArrayList<GeoArea> testList = new ArrayList<GeoArea>();
        AdapterGeoArea adapter = new AdapterGeoArea(_myContext, testList);
        for(GeoArea childGeoArea:curGeoArea.subGeoAreas){
            testList.add(childGeoArea);
        }
        holder.listViewChildGeoAreas.setAdapter(adapter);
```